# angularjs, dropdown first item issue

Tags: angularjs

I have a question. In this dropdown instead of 'select one',i want it to start directly with 'black' item. But i couldn't do it. I have just started to learn angularjs. I need your help.

Here's a link : jsfiddle.net/pixelchemist/teMUR/

Comment: please add more information abut your question like code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scope, set `myColor` to the value you want it to be on initalization.

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {


    $scope.colors = [{
        name: 'black',
        shade: 'dark'
    }, {
        name: 'white',
        shade: 'light'
    }, {
        name: 'red',
        shade: 'dark'
    }, {
        name: 'blue',
        shade: 'dark'
    }, {
        name: 'yellow',
        shade: 'light'
    }];
$scope.myColor =  $scope.colors[0];

});
```